# How do I get print() and input() to be different colors in visual studio code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, colors, workflow, color-scheme

I'm Genesis and I've been looking everywhere for an answer to this but long story short i used to be able to have my file editor look like this with print() and input() having two different distinct colors. print() had pink and the input() function was blue [older look that I want back](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/87259615/126915044-e14cbafc-12f5-4cc4-bce6-74cabfb30a10.PNG) but now since I had to reset my computer my viewer that helped me fix it is super busy with stuff and nobody can help me out with it. Now print() and input() are all blue and don't have different colors?

ultimately I tried asking viewers for help but we cant figure it out so I'm resorting to stack overflow to see if someone can solve this mystery. if you can reply what I must do to get this working back again like the picture above that would be great. I want print() & input() to have two different colors so I can know what is what and not get confused it's just how my workflow has been and please I am new to coding so I know putting comments on every single line is not convention but its just a workflow thing that i must break out of to make my code more readable. Thanks again in advance!

Here's what my print() and input() functions look like now
[image to current look of print & input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzz2s.png)

also if you have twitch and would like helping me out on stream so you can walk me through it I'm mostly live and here's my channel! https://m.twitch.tv/genesisgir
Thanks (:

Comment: What's the color theme you have used? I tried a lot of color themes both of them can not distinguish the `input` and `print`.

Comment: Well i used a color scheme called noctis and used the noctis bordo theme! But till this day still having the same color issue. its an extension called noctis @Steven-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out since i didn't remember which extensions I was using at the time VSC has a github section where you can sign into github via Visual Studio. I signed in and all of my extensions were synced and the plugin I was looking for was installed so If your having trouble getting an extension try signing in github via VS.